# C++ Segmenation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have read about segmentation faults, but fail to see why one should be caused by the following code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int input;
  cout << "Enter length of desired array." << "\n";
  cin >> input;

  int A [input];

  //Populate and print the Array.
  for(int i=0; i<sizeof(A); i++){
    A[i] = rand()%99;
    cout << A[i] << " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have a variable-sized array in C++ normally. Which compiler is this?

Comment: I have no idea what is in input; cin does convert numbers to integer. The int may be too large. I assume that you have determined that input is indeed an integer > 0 <stackSize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. You're using variable-length arrays. It's not allowed in C++. So it must be a compiler extension.
2. `sizeof(A)` returns the size in bytes, not the number of elements. Therefore you are overrunning the array. You need to divide it by the size of each element.

You should change your loop to this:

```
for(int i=0; i < input; i++){
```

---

**EDIT :** Here's a solution that doesn't use variable length arrays:

```
int main(){
    int input;
    cout << "Enter length of desired array." << "\n";
    cin >> input;

    int *A = new int[input];   //  Allocate

    //Populate and print the Array.
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(A); i++){
        A[i] = rand()%99;
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }

    delete[] A;    //  Free the allocated memory

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable length? Sorry if this seems stupid, I'm moving from Java.

Comment: Variable length arrays means an array that does not have a size that can be determined at compiled time. In this case, the size of the array is determined at run-time from the user-input. Therefore, it is a variable length array.

Comment: How would I do this in C++ then?

Comment: You can either use the `vector` class or allocate an `int` array using `new`. (and be sure you free later with `delete`) It should be easy to google around for the exact syntax.

Answer (score 8):

`sizeof` gives you size in bytes. to find element count, divide the array size in bytes by the size in of an element:

```
for(int i=0; i < sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]); i++)
```

What you are doing essentialy is writing 3 times (on most systems) the size of the array past the end, which causes segfault.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't even be using arrays.
`std::vector<T>` has a constructor `vector(size_t n)` which creates `n` elements.

Comment: That's very last decade :-) Contemporary C++ has two constructors, one `vector(size_t n)` and one `vector(size_t n, T&)` -- no more redundant copies!

Comment: cppreference.com is kind of outdated. And you meant to say `vector(size_t n, T& t, Alloc& a = Alloc())`. See [vector.cons] (23.3.6.2).

Comment: Strage, cppreference should be on top of things... hopefully soon. Not sure how one contributes to that site.

Comment: Sorry, i meant cplusplus.com. Cppreference is nice and updated, I have a local copy of it in my `~`, and I use it as primary documentation for C++11 compliance. Of course, when it conflicts with ISO 14882, ISO 14882 supersedes.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size of its argument in multiples of `sizeof(char)`. On your platform a `int` is bigger than a `char`, so you are walking off the end of the array and undefined (read *really bad*) things are allowed to happen when you do that. Be happy it's just a seg-fault.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be using the `new` and `delete` keywords for dynamic memory. I'm surprised this compiles as input is not const.

Answer (score 0):

To have variable length arrays, `int A [input];` you're gonna have to dinamically allocate it:

In C:
`int A* = malloc(input * sizeof(int));` remember to `free(A);` when you're done.

In C++:
`int A* = new int[input];` remember to `delete [] A;` when you're done.

Comment: C++ != C. use `new` instead of `malloc`.